# adding products in different column in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Hi guys I want to add products in differents column in database, however all I have done it was inserting all products in same column. thanks

my code:

```
$products = $request->all();


foreach( $products as $product) {

$invoice->products([        
'name' => $product['name'],
'price' => $product['price'],
'qty' => $product['qty'],
'total' => $product['total']
]);
}
```

results

[database shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjBMi.png)

Comment: post a sample of `print_r($product);` or `dd($product);`

Comment: Thanks for reply,i managed to get this bit sorted.

Comment: ok then please post your answer to close your question I will upvote it

Comment: this is what I did

Comment: $products = $request->all();
        
        
          $name = $products['name'];
          $price = $products['price'];
          $qty = $products['qty'];
          $total = $products['total'];
        
         foreach( $name as $key => $n) {
             
            $invoice->products()->create([ 
                
                'invoice_id' => $invoice->id,
                'name' => $name[$key],
                'price' => $price[$key],
                'qty' => $qty[$key],
                'total' => $total[$key]
            ]);}

Comment: post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry new here

```
$products = $request->all();


      $name = $products['name'];
      $price = $products['price'];
      $qty = $products['qty'];
      $total = $products['total'];

     foreach( $name as $key => $n) {

        $invoice->products()->create([ 

            'invoice_id' => $invoice->id,
            'name' => $name[$key],
            'price' => $price[$key],
            'qty' => $qty[$key],
            'total' => $total[$key]
        ]);
     }
```